# explicitly typed binding problem in Haskell

Tags: haskell

**Problem Description**

1. I have used the following code to to
   access *list of tuples* im not
   getting why im getting this error is
   ...
2. also i would like to know if i
   provided the execas
   `mn::[(1,2,3),(6,7,8)]` how can i
   acess the `(6,7,8)` ?

---

**Pure Function**

```
type rty= [(Int,Int,Int)]

mn::rty->Int
mn (a,b,c) = a
```

---

**Error Message**

```
Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : (a,b,c)
*** Type           : (a,b,c)
*** Does not match : rty
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rty is the same as `[(a, b, c)]`, a list. You are matching against a tuple instead of a list. Maybe what you want is:

```
mn [] = ?
mn ((a, b, c):xs) = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The pattern `(a,b,c)` matches triples, not lists of triples (`rty`).
2. If you want to access the second element in a list of triples, you'll have to use some kind of recursive solution (explicit or through a library function). It rather depends on what `mn` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to match a single tuple, but not a list of tuples. I'd suggest you to change the type:

```
mn :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
mn (a,_,_) = a
```

To access the n-th element of a list, use `(!!)` like in `xs !! 2`. Please note, that the function is not safe. This is, if the list is too short, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

```
type rty          = [(Int,Int,Int)]

mn                ::rty -> Int
mn ((a,b,c):xs)   = a
```

Since rty is a list of tuples, you must get a tuple out of the rty and then return it.